# boost graph library graph construction; adding edge properties iteratively

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I'm trying to define a graph using the boost graph library. I've read from a text file to get the from_to_and_distance matrix as defined below.  I was planning to simply iterate through the matrix to define the edges of the graph but am failing to understand how to define the edge properties using this method.  Specifically, I'd like to use the distance_from_a_to_b variable, as defined below, and assign it each subject edge.  I am relatively new to c++, as you may see, so while the library docs may have the answer, I can't seem to understand it.  Can someone please help?  I plan to feed this graph into a dijkstra algorithm after it is complete - if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance!

```
struct site_properties{
};

struct reach_properties{
    double distance;
};

//Note that from_to_and_distance_matrix is std::vector<std::vector<double> > and
//includes inner vectors of [from_node,to_node,distance] 

boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,boost::vecS,boost::directedS,site_properties,reach_properties> graph(unique_node_ids.size());

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < from_to_and_distance_matrix.size(); i++){
    int node_a = (int)from_to_and_distance_matrix[i][0];
    int node_b = (int)from_to_and_distance_matrix[i][1];

    //How do I assign the distance_from_a_to_b variable to the edge?!
    double distance_from_a_to_b = from_to_and_distance_matrix[i][2];

    boost::add_edge(node_a,node_b,graph);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're going to feed it to dijkstra (I assume `dijkstra_shortest_paths`), you could make it simpler by storing your distances in the `edge_weight` property, which that algorithm will read by default.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>

int main()
{
    // [from_node,to_node,distance] 
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> from_to_and_distance_matrix =
        {{0,1,0.13}, {1,2,0.1}, {1,3,0.2},
         {2,3,0.1}, {1,3,0.3}, {2,4,0.1}};

    using namespace boost;
    typedef adjacency_list<listS, vecS, directedS, no_property,
                           property<edge_weight_t, double>> graph_t;
    graph_t g;
    for(auto& v: from_to_and_distance_matrix)
        get(edge_weight, g)[add_edge(v[0], v[1], g).first] = v[2];

    std::cout << "Loaded graph with " << num_vertices(g) << " nodes\n";

    // call Dijkstra
    typedef graph_traits<graph_t>::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
    std::vector<vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(g)); // predecessors
    std::vector<double> d(num_vertices(g)); // distances
    vertex_descriptor start = vertex(0, g); // starting point
    vertex_descriptor goal = vertex(4, g); // end point

    dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, start,
                            predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]));

    // print the results
    std::stack<vertex_descriptor> path;
    for(vertex_descriptor v = goal; v != start; v = p[v])
        path.push(v);
    path.push(start);

    std::cout << "Total length of the shortest path: " << d[4] << '\n'
              << "The number of steps: " << path.size() << '\n';
    while(!path.empty()) {
        int pos = path.top();
        std::cout << '[' << pos << "] ";
        path.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

online demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f065507bb5bef35

Comment: +1. [Another alternative](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1308ab5ce408909b) that keeps using bundled properties based on the code in this answer.